# midi2audio/FluidSynth: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python-3.x, midi, audio-converter, fluidsynth

I am using the python package midi2audio to translate a midi file into a WAV.

Running:

```
filepath = 'C:/Users/Jack/Documents/GaTech/Research/Code/Data/Midi/C4/test12.mid'
soundfont = 'C:/Users/Jack/Downloads/weedsgm3.sf2'    
fs = FluidSynth(soundfont)


if os.path.isfile(filepath):
   print('The File Exists')
else: 
   print('The File does not exist')

fs.midi_to_audio(filepath, 'output.wav')
```

Outputs:

```
The File Exists
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

To be clear the error is referencing the file specified in filepath and not soundfont. There is little documentation on the package so I am not sure what to do.

Has anyone with experience with midi2audio experienced the same issue and know what is the root of the problem?

Comment: What is the actual value of `filepath`?

Comment: I added the full code which includes the filepath

Answer (score 1):

```
fs = FluidSynth()
```

This creates a `FluidSynth` object, with the default values for all the constructor's parameters.

```
FluidSynth(sample_rate=22050)
```

This creates a second `FluidSynth` object. The object reference is not assigned to any variable, so it is thrown away immediately.

```
FluidSynth(soundfont)
```

And a third object.

```
fs.midi_to_audio(filepath, 'output.wav')
```

The object referenced by `fs` uses the default sound font and the default sample rate.

You have to give all the parameters to the constructor at once:

```
fs = FluidSynth(sound_font=soundfont, sample_rate=22050)
```

(And it might be a good idea to specify the full path to the output file.)

Comment: Hey I'm getting this error even if I'm trying to use the default sample_rate and soundfont...Also tried with the absolute path of both the input and the output but to no avail. Any help on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: @AnselD'souza To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.